# smallest value between difference of two columns mysql

Tags: mysql

please, I want to select from mysql tables where the absolute difference between two columns is the smallest value between the absolute difference values.

I tried this syntax but it was not right

```
SELECT strike FROM options_20161230 ORDER BY ask - bid ASC LIMIT 1
```

I wonder if I can create a new column in the table as the difference between two columns, is that possible?

also I want to select where one column has a value between two numbers, I tried this

```
SELECT strike FROM options_20161230 WHERE 7 < Expiration - Datadate < 37 AND type ='put' AND UnderlyingSymbol = 'SPY'
```

it works when limited Expiration - Datadate by one value < 37. however It was not working with two values <,> ?

any idea please!

Many Thanks

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one please.

Comment: sorry, should I edit it and put them in a separate posts?

Comment: Now you've got answers for both. Just don't do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is close.  You just want `abs()`:

```
SELECT strike
FROM options_20161230
ORDER BY abs(ask - bid) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Your third query should use between (assuming the difference is an integer) or two inequalities:

```
SELECT strike
FROM options_20161230
WHERE Expiration - Datadate BETWEEN 8 AND 36 AND
      type ='put' AND
      UnderlyingSymbol = 'SPY';
```

Comment: Thank u, this is a great help for the 2nd part, but still not working for the smallest value. Thx